# Hash table's resizing crashes program

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashtable

I'm trying to implement Hash Table in c++ using STL list of pairs. Initial maxSize I set to 1, and I'd like to increase hash table's size twice as soon as its currentSize is greater than 75% of maximum capacity. I am getting error "Cannot dereference end list operator". Here is my implementation:

```
template<class V>
class HashTable {
public:
    int currentSize;
    int maxSize;
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> > *arr;

    HashTable() {
        this->currentSize = 0; 
        this->maxSize = 1; 
        this->arr = new std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> >[maxSize];
        arr->assign(maxSize, std::pair<std::string, V>());
    }
    ~HashTable() {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    void add(std::string key, V value) {
        if (currentSize >= 0.75 * maxSize) {
            rehash();
        }
        currentSize++;
        int idx = hashFunction(key);
        std::list<std::pair<std::string, int> >::iterator it = arr->begin();
        std::advance(it, idx);
        it = arr->erase(it);
        arr->insert(it, std::pair<std::string, V> (key, value));
    }

    int hashFunction(std::string key) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            total += int(key[i]) * pow(31, key.length() - i - 1);
        }
        return total % maxSize;
    }

    void rehash() {
        maxSize *= 2;
        std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> > *newArr = new std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> >[maxSize];
        newArr->assign(maxSize, std::pair<std::string, V>());
        for (auto it = arr->begin(); it != arr->end(); it++) {
                int idx = hashFunction(it->first);
                it = arr->begin();
                std::advance(it, idx);
                it = arr->erase(it);
                newArr->insert(it, std::pair<std::string, V>(it->first, it->second));
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = newArr;
    }
```

Interesting fact to point is that when I hard-code the maxSize for example by setting it to 20 and then adding 2 elements, it works and outputs e.g. "1: abc -> 123, 5: bca -> 42".

Comment: `std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> > *arr;` -- Why not `std::vector<std::list<std::pair<std::string, V> >> arr;`?  That removes you having to do any manual memory management.

Comment: I see a [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) violation, though I'm not sure if this is the cause of errors. Why do you use manual memory management instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: And you don't seem to use that array. You only ever use first element of that array.

Comment: `int main() { HashTable<int> h1; HashTable<int> h2 = h1; }` -- That simple program has a double-delete error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

In your `rehash`:

```
it = arr->erase(it);
```

`erase()` always returns an iterator to the value that follows the one that was just erased. That's how it works. So, if `it` already happened to be referencing the last value in `arr`, `erase()` removes it and effectively returns `end()`. Afterwards:

```
for (  ... ; it++)
```

This ends up increment `it`, as always. But in this case `it` is already `end()`. Incrementing the `end()` iterator value is undefined behavior.

Additionally:

```
newArr->insert(it, ...
```

`it` is not an iterator to `newArr`, it is an iterator to another container. An iterator can only be passed as a parameter to its own container's `insert()`. More undefined behavior.